# How mock result of redux thunk action for component (just function mock instead of request)

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have component that use thunk action.

And inside the component, I have an asynchronous execution that, after processing, returns the username to the markup, how to lock the result of such an execution

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import setTestData  from "../redux/asyncServices/testService";

function TestPage() {

  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const user = useSelector((state) => state.testReducer.user)
  const loading = useSelector((state) => state.testReducer.loading)

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(setTestData())
  }, [])


  return (
      <div className='users_wrapper'>
        <div className='container'>
          <div className='users_content'>
            <div className='title'>
              <h1>Test</h1>
            </div>
            {
              !loading ? <h1>{user.name}</h1> : null
            }
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  )
}


export default TestPage
```

Async action

```
import { createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import db from '../../indexedDB/db'
import '../../indexedDB/db.timesheetHooks'

const setTestData = createAsyncThunk(
    'setTestData',
    async () => {
     const user = await db.loggedUser.orderBy('id').last()
      return {user}
    },
)
```

And code where I try to mock function result, but something went wrong.I understand how mock simple function in jest, but how mock in this case

```
jest.mock('../redux/asyncServices/testService', () => {
  return {
    setTestData: () => ({type: "setTestData/fulfilled", payload: {
        user: {name: 'Loaded user name'}
      }}),
  };
});


describe('Timesheet Menu page tests', () => {

  beforeEach(async () => {
    matchMedia = new MatchMediaMock()

  })

  afterEach(() => {
    matchMedia.clear()
  })


  test('Component renders correctly', async () => {
    const testFn = require('../pages/TestPage');
    jest.spyOn(testFn, 'setTestData').mockReturnValue('c');
    await waitFor(() => {
      renderWithRedux(<TestPage/>, {initialState})
    })

    expect(screen.getByText('Test')).toBeInTheDocument()
    expect(screen.getByText('Loaded user name')).toBeInTheDocument()
  })
})
```

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve this?